# How to automatically extract a list from this dropdown menu?

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to use Javascript to extract a list of all the items in a dropdown list please?

[To clarify: by "extract" i just mean parse the text and display a list]

So, for example, for [this dropdown](https://sockie.w3spaces.com/drop-down-clothing-sizes.html), I would want to generate something like this:

- 4-6 years
- 8-10 years
- 3-4 years
- 10-12 years
- 6-8 years

(or it can all be on one line, it doesn't have to be a bulleted list.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the `select` element and then you have access to it's options:

```js
const select = document.getElementById("size-select");
const options = [...select.options].map(i => i.value);

// if you want to write them to the document:
document.write(options.join('<br>'));
```

Comment: thanks. Do I need to add anything after these 2 lines? for example do I need to do a for loop and to use `document.write` ?  Sorry for being dim!

Comment: @Sockie see the updated answer please, if it answers your question, please accept it as the answer.

Comment: @Sockie [Don't use `document.write`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/802854/1048572). But you should clarify in your question what you mean by "extracting"

Comment: excellent, thanks!